# adjusting column width in printing css

Tags: html, css, printing

in the print preview i am trying to make all the header columns to align in one row.....
but some of the heading takes another row since the letters in the column are more....
how to make all the heading of the columns to align in one row......
i adjusted each and every column width in media css....but still the column is not expanding to make it one line
providing my code below......

http://jsfiddle.net/e5JEH/embedded/result/

```
  @media print {

            body {margin:0; padding:0; line-height: 1.4em; word-spacing:1px; letter-spacing:0.2px; font: 12px Arial, Helvetica,"Lucida Grande", serif; color: #000;}


            .mainDiv {
                display: none;
            }



              #soLeft{ 
                width: 300px;
                /*border: 1px solid red; */
                background-color: green;
              }

              #billLabelLeft{ /*border: 1px solid red;*/ font-size: 12px; width: 50px;}
              #billTextSO{ width: 221px; /*border: 1px solid red;*/}
              .form-horizontal .controls {
                margin-left: 5px;
              }
              .form-horizontal .control-label {
                text-align: left;
                width: 50px;
              }
              #attentionTextSo{ width: 221px; }
              #addressTextSo{ width: 221px; }
              #cityTextSo{width: 70px; margin-left: 25px; height: 13px; }
              #stateLabelLeftSo{display: inline-block; margin-left: 4px;/* border: 1px solid red;*/ background-color: green; -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact; }
              #stateTextSo{width: 20px;  height: 13px;}
              #zipLabelLeftSo{display: inline-block; margin-left: 1px;}                   
              #zipTextSo{width: 25px; height: 13px;}
              #countryTextSo{width: 90px; margin-left: 5px; height: 13px;}
              #phoneTextSo{width: 70px; height: 13px;}
              #emailTextSo{width: 50px;}
              #userListSO{margin-left: 20px;color: white; display: inline-block; background-color: #cc3333;}
              #addUsersSO{color: white; display: inline-block; background-color: #cc3333;}
              #textLeftSO{
                display: none;
                /*width: 221px; margin-left: 58px;*/
              }
              #mainTextLeftSO{width: 221px;}
              #emailControlSO{width: 25px; display: inline-block;margin-left: 59px; margin-left: 40px;  margin-right: 20px;}
              #emailLabelSO{width: 11px;}


              #soRight{
                display: inline-block; 
               /* border: 1px solid red; */
                clear: left;
                position: relative;
                bottom: 160px;
                /*bottom: 250px;*/
                width: 300px; 
                float: right;
              }
              #shipSORight{width: 221px;}
              #attentionSORight{width: 221px;}
              #addressSORight{width: 221px;}
              #citySORight{width: 70px; margin-left: 25px; height: 13px; /*border: 1px solid red;*/}
              #stateSORight{width: 20px;  height: 13px; }
              #stateLabelSORight{display: inline-block; border: 1px solid right; margin-left: 1px;}               
              #zipSORight{width: 22px; height: 13px;}
              #zipLabelSORight{display: inline-block; margin-left: 4px;}
              #countrySORight{width: 90px; margin-left: 2px; height: 13px;}
              #phoneSORight{width: 70px; height: 13px;}
              #addressListSORight{color: white; display: inline-block; background-color: #cc3333; margin-left: 55px;}
              #newAddressSORight{color: white;  display: inline-block; background-color: #cc3333;}
              #storeFilesText{width: 140px;}
              #storeFilesButtonSO{margin-left: 140px; display: inline-block; background-color: #666; color: white;}
              #uploadFilesText{width: 125px;}
              #uploadFilesButtonSO{margin-left: 130px; display: inline-block; background-color: #666; color: white;}
              #downloadFilesText{width: 125px;}
              #downloadFilesButtonSO{margin-left: 115px; display: inline-block; background-color: #666; color: white;}
              #filesSO{width: 31px;}

              #fileContainerSO{
                display: none;
              }



               #storeFilesControl{
                width: 15px; display: inline-block;margin-left: 1px; margin-left: 10px;

              }

              #uploadFilesControl{
                width: 15px; display: inline-block;margin-left: 45px;
              }

              #downloadFilesControl{
                width: 15px; display: inline-block;margin-left: 45px;
              }

              #referenceSO{
                display: none;
              }

              #soTable{
                position: relative;
                bottom: 150px;
               /* bottom: 250px;*/
                border: 1px solid right;
              }

              .vendorListHeading {
                background-color: #1a4567;
                color: white;
                -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact; 
              }
              #soSecondTable{
                position: relative;
                bottom: 150px;
               /* bottom: 250px;*/
               /*  border: 1px solid green;*/
              }

              #quoteNumberPO{/*border: 1px solid red;*/ width: 310px;}
              #shippingMethodPO{width: 310px;border: 1px solid black;}
              #shippingAccountPO{width: 310px;border: 1px solid black;}

              #paddingEP{padding-left: 37px;}

              #QaPO{width: 6px;border: 1px solid black;}

              #decriptionPO{width: 992px;/*border: 1px solid red;*/ }

              #unitPricePO{width: 180px;/*border: 1px solid red;*/ }


              #partIDPO{ border: 1px solid black;}

              #paddingFirstEP{text-align: center;}


              #mfgNamePO{ border: 1px solid black; }
              #soLastRow{
                position: relative;
                bottom: 170px;
               /* bottom: 250px;*/
                /*border: 1px solid green;*/
              }

              #soTextConatiner{
                display: inline-block; margin-left: 1px;
                /*border: 1px solid red;*/
              }

               #soFirstTextLastRow{
                width: 125px;
              }

              #soSecondTextConatiner{display: inline-block; margin-left: 4px; }
              #soSecondTextLastRow{width: 124px;}

              #subTotalContainer{width: 160px; display: inline-block; margin-left: 79px;/* border: 1px solid red;*/}
              #markUpSoContainer{
                display: none;
              /*width: 258px; display: inline-block; position: relative; bottom: 81px; left: 440px; border: 1px solid red;*/}


              #printSOButtons{
                display: none;
              }

              #saveButton, #saveEmailButton, #printSummaryButton, #printDetailsButton{margin-top: 0px;}


/*

              #subTotalPrice{margin-left: 76px; }
              #taxPrice{margin-left: 170px;}
              #shippingPrice{margin-left: 106px;}
              #totalPrice{margin-left: 102px;}

*/
 #subTotalPrice{margin-left: 10px; }
              #taxPrice{margin-left: 107px;}
              #shippingPrice{margin-left: 38px;}
              #totalPrice{margin-left: 37px;}























          }


<div class="bs-docs-example" id="soTable" style="padding-top: 10px;">
              <table class="table" style="margin-bottom: 0px;width: 100%; max-width: 100%; background-color: transparent; border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0;">
                <thead>
                  <tr class="vendorListHeading" style="background-color: #1a4567;color: white; -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;">
                    <th id="datePO">Date</th>
                    <th id="referencePO">PO Number</th>
                    <th id="termPO">Term</th>
                    <th id="taxPO">Tax</th>
                    <th id="quoteNumberPO">Quote Number</th>
                    <th id="statusPO">Status</th>
                    <th id="buyerPO">Account Mgr</th>
                    <th id="shippingMethodPO">Shipping Method</th>
                    <th id="shippingAccountPO">Shipping Account</th>
                    <th id="QaPO">QA</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  <tr class="">
                    <td style="border: 1px solid black;">22</td>
                    <td style="border: 1px solid black;">20130000</td>
                    <td style="border: 1px solid black;">Jim B.</td>
                    <td style="border: 1px solid black;">22</td>
                    <td style="border: 1px solid black;">510 xxx yyyy</td>
                    <td style="border: 1px solid black;">zznn@abc.co</td>
                    <td style="border: 1px solid black;">PDF</td>
                    <td style="border: 1px solid black;">12/23/2012</td>
                    <td style="border: 1px solid black;">Approved</td>
                    <td style="border: 1px solid black;">PDF</td>
                  </tr>

                </tbody>
              </table>
            </div>
```

Comment: If I print in landscape layout, look fine for me. Eachtable header fill one row.

Answer (score 1):

create a print only style sheet, you create them exactly the same with with standard CSS except you try and use EM instead of PX. When you `<link` the css to the html page, you make sure to add in the attribute `media="print"` which will make the style sheet a print only style sheet. take a look at http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/24/how-to-set-up-a-print-style-sheet/ for further reference

Comment: i used the media print css code...i have provided above but still not working